# Magento2 Rest API for add to compare

Tags: magento2, compare, pwa

Magento2 - PWA. I am developing PWA in Magento2. In products I am not able to see Add to compare link.

How can I create add to compare REST API & use it in PWA?

Answer (score 0):

This extension is helpful to you.
https://marketplace.magento.com/magedad-module-compareapi.html